# What do .. and * mean in aspectj

Tags: java, annotations, aspectj

My understanding is that `..` is `0-Many` args and `*` is one arg of `any` name. Is this correct?

Does aspectj support syntax like `args(..,myArg,..)`?

Comment: var-arg can only be the last argument (at the end) in Java.

Comment: It would be very difficult/impossible for the compiler/interpreter to know which argument passed was actually `myArg` in your case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is from AspectJ site: http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html

`*` represents any number of characters except "."

`..` represents any number of characters including any number of "."

**Update**
From AspectJ in Action - for method signatures:

> In method signatures, the wildcard .. is used to denote any type and number of arguments taken by a method

`*` specifies a single argument

Comment: but also this : "If it is the "*" wildcard, then any argument will match, and if it is the special wildcard "..", then any number of arguments will match"

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have updated the answer accordingly for method signatures also. AspectJ does not support `(.., myarg, ..)`, not sure why though.

Answer (score 6):

Others have answered part of the question before me, so I will only amend:

`.., bla, ..` does not work because if you bind parameter `bla` to a variable, there might be several matching combinations in case a matching type occurs multiple times in the parameter list. Example:

`void foo(int a, String b, String c, File d)`

Now what should happen if the advice is:

`before(String bla) : call(void foo(.., bla, ..)) && args(bla)`

Should `bla` be bound to the `String` value of `b` or `c`?