# what is delimiter in excel file to export data to oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, loader

I have to extract data from excel file to oracle table using sql loader

i was wondering what could be the delimiter for excel file

can we take a tab as delimiter for excel file??

Comment: what about '\n' as delimiter

Answer (score 0):

You can set the options whilst you 'Save As'.  When you select the dropdown box for 'Save as type', you will find in the list:

- **Text (Tab Delimited)**.  This will save the file with the extension `.txt` which you can then rename as required - TAB delimited (obviously)
- **CSV**. This will produce a comma delimited file.

Those are your best options to produce data files that most RDBMSs will be able to work with.

Comment: also - possible duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120001/load-excel-data-sheet-to-oracle-database