# Creating an SEO friendly url with .htaccess and php from a mysql field

Tags: php, .htaccess, rest, url, seo

My website creates urls like the following: /index.php?placeid=27

I want to be able to change the url to display the place name, so something like: 
/southampton

where the placename is another database field displayed on the content of each page. I guess this requires some php and `.htaccess` solution which puts a variable into the url, but I can't seem to work this out from any similar questions on here. Thanks.

Comment: You can try using [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect to dynamic content with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473705/how-to-redirect-to-dynamic-content-with-htaccess)