# Replace part of oracle database with data in excel

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table with 103 columns and more than 100,000 records. I was told that Oracle Data base has bad data in few of the columns(four columns) and in few of the records(20,000 records approx) and was told to modify data. Also I was given a query where I should modify data(bad data). With the help of query, I exported all the bad data into excel and modified using macros.

How to replace existing bad data in Oracle data base to data which I have in excel(good data). Is it possible to modify data in some part of the database using SQL query?  I mean to say 4 out of 103 columns and 20k out of 100k records has to be modified without affecting already existing good data in Oracle database.

I am using SQL developer and Oracle 11g

My query to retrieve bad data

```
select e.id_number
, e.gender_code
, e.pref_mail_name
, e.prefix
,e.first_name
,e.last_name
,e.spouse_name
,e.spouse_id_number
,e.pref_jnt_mail_name1
,e.pref_jnt_mail_name2                                                                      
from advance.entity e                                                                        
where e.person_or_org = 'P'                                                                   
and ascii(e.spouse_name) <> 32                                                               
or ascii(e.spouse_id_number) <> 32"
```

Note: Moreover I am not changing any primary key or secondary key data. Bad data is in other columns.

Comment: I think you're looking for the `UPDATE` statement. [Documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10008.htm#SQLRF01708). With a bit of work with Excel formulas it's possible to generate the required `UPDATE` statements in the Excel spreadsheet, then copy these over to SQL Developer (or whatever tool you have) and execute them. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by importing all corrected data (which now resides in your Excel file), to a **temporary table**. See [Load Excel data sheet to Oracle database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120001/load-excel-data-sheet-to-oracle-database) for more details.

The it should be a simple task to write one or more `UPDATE` [statements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10008.htm#SQLRF01708). If you are new to Oracle syntax, [Tech on the Net has some nice examples](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/update.php).

Also, do not forget to backup the original table to a temporary table before you make any changes there. That way, if you mess up the data repair, you can start over.