# How to load Excel data sheet(multiple sheets) to oracle database without converting in to other formats(csv,txt))

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I used SQL loader it works fine if i have single sheet but i encountered few obstacles while loading multiple sheets in to a pre-existing table. could any one suggest me the best way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load Excel data sheet to Oracle database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120001/load-excel-data-sheet-to-oracle-database)

Comment: tl;dr you can't. You either need to parse the xls(x) in a different language and load that row by row of convert it.

Comment: finally i have done it by Apache POI..