# Procedure to Import Excel to Oracle 11g in SQL Navigator?

Tags: oracle11g

We have SQL Navigator 6.1 for Oracle 11g.I have to Import an Excel file which has around 100 row of records and 15 columns.

I am looking for sample procedures which will help me to import an excel file to oracle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load Excel data sheet to Oracle database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120001/load-excel-data-sheet-to-oracle-database)

Comment: If you have a MS Access you can import your xls there and then export to an external db. It's quite simple and friendly.

Comment: That sounds like a good plan

Comment: @Multisync , Thank you. I did it as per your advise. I exported from excel to access and from access to oracle